# How to get list of end points for a Apigee proxy

Tags: apigee, apigee127

I am looking for an Api or set of Apis to get list of all end-points for an Apigee proxy.  I looked around apigee docs, but I could only list proxies and its revisions.

Answer (score 0):

This may be imperfect and could be optimized, but I think it works. Combine three calls:

1 to determine which revisions of which proxies are actually deployed into certain environments: 
  e.g., https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/[org]/environments/[env]/deployments
  or: https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/[org]/apis/[proxy]/deployments

2 to see which proxyEndpoints are configured for a particular revision of a proxy
  e.g., https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/[org]/apis/[proxy]/revisions/[revision #]

3 to see which vhost hostAliases those proxyEndpoints refer:
  e.g., https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/[org]/environments/[env]/virtualhosts/[vhost name]

Frustratingly the Edge admin UI offers a shortcut via a private 'status' call to https://[xxx].apigee.com/ws/proxy/organizations/[org]/apis/[proxy]/deployments/status, but that's not accessible from the REST API.